# Why have I got so many ngen.exe processes?

Tags: windows-10

recently I've been looking through my task manager and I saw that I have loads of ngen.exe processes. Does anyone know why and if I can get rid of them, I never had them before but I started fiddling around with .net framework to try and get my ObjectDock to work.

[image]

Comment: CLR v4 x64, CLR v4 x86, CLR v2 x64, CLR v2 x86. Total: 4 different `ngen.exe` processes.

Comment: Yeah this ngen.exe process is for .net framework 2.0 even through I have .net framework 4.5 or something.

Comment: ngen is also aprt of .net 4.6. The posted answer is correct. This is the scheduled maintenance task of Windows that runs

Comment: But it says that its ngen from 2.0?

Comment: It's alright now, I just unticked it from Windows Features then allowed Windows to reinstall it and it is only running ngen.exe from 4.0 now. Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe) is a tool that improves the performance of managed applications. Ngen.exe creates native images, which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code, and installs them into the native image cache on the local computer.
More information at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information but I have .net framework 4.5 or something and these ngen.exe processes are for .net framework 2.0 any idea how to remove them?

Comment: Uninstall Microsoft .NET Framework from your system.

Comment: It doesn't show up, just visual redists are showing.

Comment: Try to repair .Net framework using this tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135 if still not work, remove the .NET framework using this tool (use with your own risk) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx